# How do I rotate a label in Vb net?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to rotate a label 90 degrees in Vb net and cannot get it working. My code is as follows. Any help would be appreciated.

---

```
    Private Sub Label1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint

    Dim sf As New StringFormat

    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center

    sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center

    MetroLabel50.Text = ""

    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(MetroLabel50.ClientSize.Width, MetroLabel50.ClientSize.Height)

    e.Graphics.RotateTransform(90)

    e.Graphics.DrawString("Label", MetroLabel50.Font, Brushes.Black, RectangleF.op_Implicit(MetroLabel50.ClientRectangle), sf)

    e.Graphics.ResetTransform()

End Sub
```

Comment: move e.Graphics.RotateTransform(90) after DrawString?

Comment: Still doesn't work I'm afraid. Having not used this before do I have to call it besides 'handles me.paint' and does it make a difference that I have already docked the label?

Comment: ok, keep that line where you had it, answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so after checking a little, this line

```
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(MetroLabel50.ClientSize.Width, MetroLabel50.ClientSize.Height)
```

should be

```
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(csng(MetroLabel50.ClientSize.Width/2), csng(MetroLabel50.ClientSize.Height/2))
```

you have to set it in the middle

also change `Handles Me.Paint` by `Handles label1.Paint`

sample code;

step 1, new project
step 2, drop a label in middle of the form
step 3, put that code

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label1.AutoSize = False
    Label1.Text = ""
    Label1.Width = 75
    Label1.Height = 75
    Label1.Refresh()
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Label1.Paint
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(CSng(Label1.Width / 2), CSng(Label1.Height / 2))
    e.Graphics.RotateTransform(90)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello", Label1.Font, Brushes.Black, New Point(0, 0))
    e.Graphics.ResetTransform()
End Sub
```

step 4, run the application

Comment: Still getting nowhere. I've put in test label text and it doesn't even blank it on load so I'm assuming the sun hasn't even started

Comment: @user6641274 make sure autosize is false, clearing the label will make it very small

Comment: Having manually typed "test" in the properties text window when the application loads I still see the word "test" . Would this not mean that the line metrolabel50.text="" has not been successful and that the sub has just not started?

Comment: @user6641274, your paint is bind to the form, do it on the label

Comment: I noticed that one a bit earlier and swapped handles me.paint to metrolabel50.paint but still no change. Do I have to invoke the sub in the load sub?

Comment: thanks for your help. It actually looks like it's something to do with using metro ui labels rather than normal ones. Once swapped for a normal label it worked perfect. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have searched a lot to figure this out so I am sharing my simple code here
I have created a PictureBox to place the text in you can change the PicBox Size after populating it to keep aspect ratio

```
Dim bmp As New Bitmap(TextToRotateLabel.Width, TextToRotateLabel.Height)
TextToRotateLabel.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, 
TextToRotateLabel.Width, TextToRotateLabel.Height))
bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone)
bmp.Save("c:\Path\text.bmp")
PicBox.Image = bmp
```

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET, the Label control doesn't have a built-in property to set the text vertically. However, you can achieve this effect by creating a custom control or by manipulating the label's appearance using graphics transformations. One common approach is to rotate the text 90 degrees to achieve a vertical effect.

```
Imports System.Drawing

Public Class VerticalLabel
    Inherits Label

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
        Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
        g.TranslateTransform(0, Me.Height)
        g.RotateTransform(-90)
        g.DrawString(Me.Text, Me.Font, New SolidBrush(Me.ForeColor), New PointF(0, 0))
    End Sub
End Class
```

1. Create a new Windows Forms project in VB.NET.
2. Add a new class to your project.
3. and name it VerticalLabel.vb.
4. Paste the above code into the VerticalLabel.vb file.
5. Build your project.

After building your project, you should see the VerticalLabel control in your toolbox. You can then add it to your form and set its properties like a regular label. Keep in mind that this implementation might need further adjustments depending on your specific use case.

**This is the simplest way that i got, but unfortunately it does lack a lot of tweaks.**